# Problem using variable gotten in void receiveEvent, inside void loop

Tags: arduino, i2c, arduino-c++

I'm doing a school project using Arduino, I want to connect 2 arduinos with each other, one being Master writer, the other slave reader.

I'm sending a character from the master to slave using `Wire.write();` and in the slave i'm reading it inside `void receiveEvent(int howMany)`.

I want to use the character received there inside the void loop, but i'm having trouble achieving that. I've tried making it a global variable and also a volatile variable, so far nothing worked.
How could I use the character inside void loop?

Comment: Usually you would have one function return the value and the other function accept a value as input. But, it's not clear to me exactly what you are trying to do here. Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/iLm8uRvg this is the code from the slave reader